Tone.js pattern "Progress" value not progressing from 0 to 1 properly
I'd like to adapt this official example on the Tone.js website to include a vertical line that indicates the current progress of the loop, as opposed to just highlighting the current note. (Think of it like the time indicator, in Audacity, for example).
The Pattern has a property called progress which I wanted to use. I thought that calling loop.progress would effectively give me the percentage (number between 0 and 1) of the loop that was complete at that moment.
I'm calling setInterval(function(){console.log(loop.progress)}, 200) every 200 ms, but the progress that is logged to the console bears no resemblance to the current progress. If anything, it seems to be cycling from 0 to 1 much faster than the true progress of the loop.
Here is the JS Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/0og17qnw/9/
Can anyone identify what's going wrong with this approach and how to get it to log the actual progress of the loop?
Thank you

In fact, slowing down the timings so it's easier to see what's happening - https://jsfiddle.net/0og17qnw/12/, it looks like the progress is going from 0 - 1 for each individual note of the pattern rather than the pattern as a whole. Surely, that can't be right?
